# Crash Log Meaning

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, crash-reports

This is the log from a crash of an app.  It crashes on startup, and I can't figure out why.  Thoughts?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1878eb09c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193869d78 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1878eafdc +[NSException raise:format:] + 128
3   UIKit                           0x18ab68c98 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 832
4   UIKit                           0x18ab6aba8 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 160
5   UIKit                           0x18aa691f8 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 52
6   UIKit                           0x18a82e8a0 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 516
7   UIKit                           0x18a7c1530 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3336
8   UIKit                           0x18a7c0720 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 104
9   UIKit                           0x18a82e0b0 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 712
10  GraphicsServices                0x18d211128 _PurpleEventCallback + 676
11  GraphicsServices                0x18d210c54 PurpleEventCallback + 48
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1878aafc8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1878aaf28 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1878a914c __CFRunLoopRun + 1620
15  CoreFoundation                  0x1877e9b38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
16  UIKit                           0x18a82d2d4 -[UIApplication _run] + 784
17  UIKit                           0x18a8280e8 UIApplicationMain + 1156
18  AirHomeVideo                    0x100050aec main (main.m:16)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x193e53aa0 start + 4
```

Comment: Obviously, the problem is related to loading your nib/xib. Do you have the source code for the app and a working Xcode environment? Are you able to run it in the simulator? On a real device? You might want to try doing a clean, and then a fresh build to see if Xcode gives any helpful warnings.

Comment: Works fine on simulator and device.  Only crashes when installing from Cydia

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Cydia. Is it possible you're using new(er) features of iOS6 or iOS7 that aren't supported in your version of Cydia? Like auto layout as an example.

Comment: @PaulDardeau If this somehow got built with the wrong configuration (Debug over Distribution) would that cause errors like this?  Where it works when SSHd directly to my phone but over Cydia it messes up?